# JDBC SQLite Дата

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

JDBC SQLite

Использую setDate при вставке в PreparedStatement.
Даты пишутся и читаются правильно.
В таблице представлены так
946674000000 - это 2001.01.01
1688158800000 - это 2023.07.01

Когда пробую применить условие между то получается проблема
Пример:
таблица.поле BETWEEN '946674000000 ' and '1688158800000'
Условие(см пример) формируется текстом на основе фильтра

Есть ли вариант оставить работу через setDate и java.sql.Date или стразу ставить строку вида '2023-07-01'

Comment: "Условие(см пример)" - и где смотреть пример? И зачем Вы оборачиваете в апострофы численные значения? Если я правильно понимаю, то значения дат в BETWEEN должны быть указаны как числа, а не как строки... Как понять "... формируется текстом на основе фильтра" и "... оставить работу через setDate"?

Comment: Какой формат используется при форматировании даты?

Answer (score 0):

После комментария XelaNimed понял, что не правильно поставил тип в поле для даты(TEXT).  Поставил INTEGER и все нормально